# Python OpenCV Ellipse - takes at most 5 arguments (8 given)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm at a total loss here on why I can't draw an ellipse with OpenCV after looking at documentation.

First I'm using CV 2.4.9

```
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.9'
>>>
```

Second, I'm attempting to use the following:

```
>>> help(cv2.ellipse)
Help on built-in function ellipse in module cv2:

ellipse(...)
    ellipse(img, center, axes, angle, startAngle, endAngle, color[, thickness[,
lineType[, shift]]]) -> None  or  ellipse(img, box, color[, thickness[, lineType
]]) -> None
```

My ellipse looks like the following:

```
cx,cy = 201,113
ax1,ax2 =  37,27
angle = -108
center = (cx,cy)
axes = (ax1,ax2)

cv2.ellipse(frame, center, axes, angle, 0 , 360, (255,0,0), 2)
```

However, running that gives me the following

```
>>> cv2.ellipse(frame,center,axes,angle,0,360, (255,0,0), 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ellipse() takes at most 5 arguments (8 given)
>>>
```

Help?

---

Edit:
I wanted to use the following as a frame

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(fileLoc)
frame = cap.read()
```

Apparently it can be fixed by using the following

```
pil_im = Image.fromarray(frame)
cv2.ellipse(frame,center,axes,angle,0,360,(255,0,0), 2)
pil_im = Image.fromarray(raw_image)
pil_im.save('C:/Development/export/foo.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, oddly it works in some instances and not in others.

Comment: Center and axes has to be an integers tuple, not floats, not single parameters.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I Had same problem and I solved it. My first line of code that I couldn't run it was:

```
cv2.ellipse(ellipMask, (113.9, 155.7), (23.2, 15.2), 0.0, 0.0, 360.0, (255, 255, 255), -1);
```

I found that axes (as well as center) has to be an integers tuple, not floats.
Therefore below line was OK!

```
cv2.ellipse(ellipMask, (113, 155), (23, 15), 0.0, 0.0, 360.0, (255, 255, 255), -1);
```

I think you should take are of other values to be in correct format.

Here is the link from Opencv's website:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/30778/how-to-draw-ellipse-with-first-python-function/

Comment: it happened to me when migrating to python 3.6 some code that originally was working fine in python 2.7. My code was doing a division to calculate the values of the axes, the result was integer was in 2.7 and turned to float in python 3 (python 3 division is float by default)

Comment: They have to be tuples, not lists. Otherwise, the same, misleading, error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my iPython session - which seemed to work fine:

```
In [54]: cv2.__version__
Out[54]: '2.4.9'

In [55]: frame = np.ones((400,400,3))

In [56]: cx,cy = 201,113

In [57]: ax1,ax2 =  37,27

In [58]: angle = -108

In [59]: center = (cx,cy)

In [60]: axes = (ax1,ax2)

In [61]: cv2.ellipse(frame, center, axes, angle, 0 , 360, (255,0,0), 2)

In [62]: plt.imshow(frame)
Out[62]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x1134ad8d0>
```

This worked - and generated the following:

[image]

So, a bit strange... Maybe there is something in the way you have imported the `cv2` module?

Or (more likely) exactly what is the type/structure of your `frame` object?

Comment: I just run this code on my end and it works too.  My guess is that there's something wrong with the `frame` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you plot from 0° to 360°, you could use floats, by calling the function with a single ellipse parameter:

```
ellipse_float = ((113.9, 155.7), (23.2, 15.2), 0.0)
cv2.ellipse(image, ellipse_float, (255, 255, 255), -1);
```

or in a one-liner:

```
cv2.ellipse(image, ((113.9, 155.7), (23.2, 15.2), 0.0), (255, 255, 255), -1);
# compared to the following which does not work if not grouping the ellipse paramters in a tuple
#cv2.ellipse(image, (113.9, 155.7), (23.2, 15.2), 0.0, 0, 360, (255, 255, 255), -1); # cryptic error
```

This won't work if you want to add startAngle and stopAngle unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```html
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
        (cX, cY) = (int(w * 0.5), int(h * 0.5))

        # divide the image into four rectangles/segments (top-left,
        # top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left)
        segments = [(0, cX, 0, cY), (cX, w, 0, cY),
                    (cX, w, cY, h), (0, cX, cY, h)]

        # construct an elliptical mask representing the center of the
        # image
        (axesX, axesY) = (int(w * 0.75) / 2, int(h * 0.75) / 2)
        ellipMask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
        cv2.ellipse(ellipMask, (int(cX), int(cY)), (int(axesX), int(axesY)), 0, 0, 360, 255, -1)
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Only try to print the input parameters and check their shape, format, and dtype to be as same as OpenCV documentation. Fixed the problem for me after finding an issue in one of the parameters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can include a specific example and code solution that resolves the problem. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).